# Add string restriction to XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have the following `Languages` element. For each Language, I want the attribute to be either "Subbed" or "Dubbed". For example:

```
<Languages>
    <Language Type="Subbed">EN</Language>
    <Language Type="Dubbed">FR</Language>
</Languages>
```

Here is the XSD I currently have -- how would I add in the "subbed|dubbed" restriction?

```
<xs:element name="Languages">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Language" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Type" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with enumerations:

**Replace**

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Type" use="optional"/>
```

**with**

```
<xs:attribute type="LanguageType" name="Type" use="optional"/>
```

**and add**

```
<xs:simpleType name="LanguageType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Subbed"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Dubbed"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**to restrict `Language/@Type` to be one of `Subbed` or `Dubbed`.**

---

**Here is the above adjustment applied to a complete XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="Languages">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Language" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="LanguageType" name="Type" use="optional"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="LanguageType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Subbed"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Dubbed"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**This will validate your XML, as requested.**

Comment: thanks for this. Would you be able to show the entire xml block for this? I'm not certain where the restriction should be placed.

Comment: Added the entire XSD that will validate your XML per your request.